# Which extent of Latex functionality/packages is available in Pandoc

Tags: packages, pandoc, conversion

*The Pandoc tool is available online at https://pandoc.org/try I use it for my conversions. Although, I am not sure whether it reflects the same capabilities as offline tool which you have to download: So opinions about my (temporary, test) workflow are welcome.*

My Latex files mostly contain following packages/instances:

- Equations
- Matrix
- Hyperlinks (hyperref)
- `draftwatermark`
- images
- lists
- columns
- custom commands for like `\em` and `\definition` for my own needs.

I will convert the files into HTML, MathML. Is there a certain list online  that lists out what are the available LaTeX functionality/packages is available in Pandoc? *(not [this which you get after installing the offline version](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/247448/247020))*

resources:

https://gist.github.com/matsest/397b0a3352fa09d83b9ee5cf6ca7d4a6

https://github.com/Wandmalfarbe/pandoc-latex-template

[Is it possible to use the "lettrine" package with pandoc?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392102/is-it-possible-to-use-the-lettrine-package-with-pandoc)

https://uoftcoders.github.io/studyGroup/lessons/misc/pandoc-intro/lesson/

https://walkingrandomly.com/?p=6549

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the LaTeX functionality is supported in pandoc. As I have learned,

- We can modify the configuration / pandoc-preamble section or
- Use an external solution (mostly coded ourselves)

to do certain changes to unsupported LaTeX code, therefore they work in the target format. But these options will *not make every LaTeX thing work*.

Therefore I got no need to find out the supporting in a online-form, bcause whether support exist or not, I will code it myself.